# Convergence in continuous distribution to gamma implies convergence of moments

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_i$ are a sequence of random variables with *continuous* distributions (possibly not absolutely continuous), such that

$$X_i \xrightarrow{d} X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(k,\theta),$$

where $d$ denotes convergence in distribution. Does necessarily

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i^m] \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X^m],$$

where $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

This question is a continuation of an [identical question without the continuity assumption](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149099/convergence-in-distribution-to-gamma-implies-convergence-of-moments); that question was answered negatively with a counterexample.

Comment: You may "fix" the discontinuity by adding a small normally distributed random variable which goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing essential about the discreteness of the second random variable $2n$ added in the mixture in the answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149099/convergence-in-distribution-to-gamma-implies-convergence-of-moments). They could have used any sequence of random variables whose means increased proportional to $n,$ including continuous ones that would produce a sequence of continuous distributions.

Comment: Right, we may replace $2n$ with $Yn$, where $Y$ has continuous distribution and $\mathbb{E}[Y] \neq 0$.

Comment: @Kaba yep, that's right